# Build a react widget in js file and reuse in asp .net mvc project

Tags: javascript, .net, reactjs, webpack

I want to know if it is possible to make a widget using React library and then build it to a single js file to re-use in any non react app (preferably in asp .net)

Comment: we can create react widget and append to any non-react application, it is possible

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, but it will bloat your js code, as react and react dom has to be packaged into this library. For only one widget, this seems to be too much overhead for me.

Comment: it's not just a widget. It is planned to be a context setting widget which involves a lot of service calls as well as capability to set the context across like 10 context dependent application through cross-domain. We can build as a module, but it is only reusable in angular or react. I need a way to reuse in asp .net